# Extract values from class instances inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code:

```
    class B():

        def __init__(self, valueA, valueB ):
            self.valueA = valueA
            self.valueB = valueB


        def __repr__(self):
            return 'B({0},{1})'.format(self.valueA, self.valueB)
```

My data is :

```
thedata = {'a': [B(1, 0.1),B(2, 0.2)],
          'b': [B(3, 0.3),B(4, 0.4)]}
```

What I want to do is extract the `a` and `b` attributes from above dictionary to 2 new dictionaries according the key.

So, I want :

```
thedata_a_valueA = {'a':[1, 2]}
thedata_a_valueB = {'a':[0.1, 0.2]}
thedata_b_valueA = {'b':[3, 4]}
thedata_b_valueB = {'b':[0.3, 0.4]}
```

and finally I want 2 dictionaries:

```
newdict_valueA = {'a':[1, 2], 'b':[3,4]}
newdict_valueB = {'a':[0.1, 0.2], 'b':[0.3,0.4]}
```

One solution is to use lists but I must create quite a few lists, loop over them, append etc

Is there any cleaner/faster solution working on `thedata` ?

Comment: Don't forget Python dictionaries don't support duplicate keys.  Therefore it's not possible to have the two 'b' keys with different values in your newdict_valueB example.

Comment: @MarkStreatfield:Sorry,it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
# Starting from two empty dictionaries
newdict_valueA, newdict_valueB = {}, {}

# Iterate over the key/value pairs of the data
for key, value in thedata.items():
    # assign to the same key of each result dictionary a list of
    # the valueA for each B item in the value of the original dictionary
    newdict_valueA[key] = [item.valueA for item in value]
    newdict_valueB[key] = [item.valueB for item in value]
```

newdict_valueA:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

newdict_valueB:

```
{'a': [0.1, 0.2], 'b': [0.3, 0.4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have all of the expected items in a list for each key in your dictionary. You just need to loop over `thedata`'s items and for each key create a dictionary contain separate items for `valueA` and `valueB`. The `dict.setdefault()` attribute would be nice choice for this task.

```
In [18]: d = {}

In [19]: for i, j in thedata.items():
             for instance in j:
                 d.setdefault(i, {}).setdefault('valueA', []).append(instance.valueA)
                 d.setdefault(i, {}).setdefault('valueB', []).append(instance.valueB)       

In [20]: d
Out[21]: 
{'a': {'valueB': [0.1, 0.2], 'valueA': [1, 2]},
 'b': {'valueB': [0.3, 0.4], 'valueA': [3, 4]}}
```

Note that as a more cleaner way you can use `collections.defaultdict()` instead of the `dict.setdefault()` method:

```
In [33]: d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

In [34]: for i, j in thedata.items():
             for instance in j:
                 d[i]['valueA'].append(instance.valueA)
                 d[i]['valueB'].append(instance.valueB)
   ....:         

In [35]: d
Out[35]: defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fb5888786a8>,
         {'a': defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
               {'valueB': [0.1, 0.2], 'valueA': [1, 2]}),
          'b': defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
               {'valueB': [0.3, 0.4], 'valueA': [3, 4]})})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you can use comprehensions:

```
newdict_valueA = { k : [ b.valueA for b in l ] for k, l in thedata.items() }
newdict_valueB = { k : [ b.valueB for b in l ] for k, l in thedata.items() }
```